# Issue with using append in small program

Tags: python, append

I wanted to test append in my small program. Unfortunately, if does the wrong thing.

**Input format**
A non-empty text in English, ending with a dot, is supplied to the input of the program (there are no other dot characters in the text).

**Output format:**
The original line and number on the new line is the number of letters 's' in a line.

```
init = input()
sentence = []
ses = 0
for i in range(len(init)):
    if init[i] == '.':
        break
    elif init[i] == 's':
        ses += 1
    elif init[i] != '.' or init[i] == 's':
        sentence.append(init[i])
print(''.join(sentence))
print(ses)
```

Input:
    It is not a simple task. Yes!
Expected output:
    It is not a simple task
    3

But it does:
    It i not a imple tak
    3

Comment: Can you show input and output sample as well as your actual output?

Comment: Is the issue here that the s's and full stops aren't being appended to the 'sentence' list?

After adding 1 to the s count, also append to sentence (to keep the s's), and before the break checking for a full stop, append the full stop too?

Comment: S's don't being appended to the list. The full stop doesn't have to be appended but that't fine. What's wrong with s's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to append the s's and full stops.

```
init = input()
sentence = []
ses = 0
for i in range(len(init)):
    if init[i] == '.':
        sentence.append(init[i])
        break
    elif init[i] == 's':
        ses += 1
        sentence.append(init[i])
    elif init[i] != '.' or init[i] == 's':
        sentence.append(init[i])
print(''.join(sentence))
print(ses)
```

the above should work perfectly

Comment: That `elif init[i] != '.' or init[i] == 's':` is pretty pointless though :) You can delete the last two lines of the loop and remove one level of indentation from the `sentence.append(init[i])` after `ses += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
init = input()
```

Let's say the user typed:

```
init = 'something is sad.'
```

Then:

```
init = init.upper()    
list_of_s = []
for letter in init:
   if letter == "S":
      list_of_s.append(letter)


print(init + str(len(list_of_s)))
```

First you should transform the input string all to upper letters to normalize the string (you could also user the method .lower()).
 
Then you define the variable list_of_s where you will store each s matched using append as you requested.
 
With Python you can iterate a string as if it was a list, each letter we check if it's equal to "S" and if it is we add one s to our list variable. 
Finally we use len() to calculate the number of s in our list and print the desired output (we must first transform the number to a string using str()).